# Get Correctly BadRequest Message after Post Angular 5

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I have validation in controller with c# like:

```
 if (user == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }
```

In Angular I try to receive it as :

```
signin() {
    this.loading = true;

    this._authService.login(this.model.email, this.model.password).subscribe(
      data => {
        this._router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
      },
      error => {
        this.showAlert('alertSignin');
        this._alertService.error(error._body);
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }
```

But `error_.body` comes with extrange format:

```
"{"":["Invalid login attempt."]}"
```

why I cant get only text of it? like:

```
Invalid login attempt.
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `ModelState` if you need only text. Use

```
if (user == null)
{    
   return BadRequest("Invalid login attempt.");
}
```